# Tried to implement RSA in python. Code is randomly failing for some reason

Tags: python, cryptography, rsa, public-key-encryption

I've just started learning cryptography and have been trying to implement RSA in python based on this article [here](https://www.comparitech.com/blog/information-security/rsa-encryption/). The thing is, my code is randomly decrypting the encrypted data incorrectly. If you run this program again and again, you'd eventually reach perfect conditions that would result in the code decrypting it correctly.

For those suggesting to use external RSA libraries: I can't because that would defeat the purpose of this project.

Here is the code:

```
#! /usr/bin/python3
from random import randint
from random import SystemRandom
from string import digits
from math import gcd


def lcm(x, y):
    return x*y // gcd(x,y)


def modinv(x, y):
    try:
        inverted = pow(x, -1, y)
        return inverted
    except ValueError:
        return 'Error: No Modular Inverse'


def sec_rand():
    while True:
        x = int(''.join(SystemRandom().choice(digits) for _ in range(3)))
        if((x % 2) == 0):
            continue
        else:
            break
    return x


def encrypt(message, public_key, n):
    encrypted = pow(message, public_key) % n
    return encrypted


def decrypt(public_key, n_carmichael_totient, crypted, n):
    private_key = modinv(public_key, n_carmichael_totient)
    decrypted = pow(crypted, private_key) % n
    return decrypted


def main():
    prime1 = sec_rand()
    prime2 = sec_rand()
    print("Prime 1: " + str(prime1))
    print("Prime 2: " + str(prime2))
    n = prime1 * prime2
    ntotient = lcm(prime1 - 1, prime2 - 1)
    plaintext = 59 
    e = 65537 # Public Key
    print("Plaintext: " + str(plaintext))
    encrypted = encrypt(plaintext, e, n)
    print("Encrypted: " + str(encrypted))
    decrypted = decrypt(e, ntotient, encrypted, n)
    print("Decrypted: " + str(decrypted))


main()
```

Comment: You are not generating primes... `Prime 1: 995`.

Comment: See [primality testing -- simple methods](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primality_test#Simple_methods).

Comment: Thank you so much guys! I can't believe I missed this.

Comment: Well, actually there are more like you don't check that `gcd(e, ntotient)=1` or not. Usually we first select `e` the generate the primes and if gcd is not 1, regenerate the primes...